# Python returning from class

Tags: python, string, class, printing

```
class Customer:  #at this part ı defined the class for the customers in the file
    def __init__(self, Name, Surname, Age, Balance):
        self.name = Name;
        self.sname = Surname;
        self.age = Age;
        self.balance = Balance;

    def __str__(self):
        return("Hello, "+str(self.name)+" "+str(self.sname)+" You have "+ str(self.balance)+" dollars in your account.");
```

Hello, you can see my class above

My aim - ask users name/surname and get the `str` part in the class. 
I'm getting informations about customers from csv file.

```
ans = input("name")
ans2 = input("surname")


a = Customer(ans,ans2)
print(a)
```

With this part I've tried to do part that I explained above but I could'nt make the code work.

Comment: What happens if you execute it? Please provide an output

Comment: Looks like you're calling Customer with only two arguments, but it needs 4?

Comment: ';' at the end of the line is not needed, It's Python after all.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define all the other attributes the class instance supposed to have that is Name, Surname, Age, Balance where you have only given Name and Surname. Python will also expect all other attributes you have given in `__init__`

Take this for example:

```
Age = input("age") #add these to take input too
Balance = input("balance") #add these to take input too
a = Customer(ans,ans2, Age, Balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your values sometimes supposed to be empty, make some values not necessary as in example:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, Name, Surname, Age=None, Balance=None): # specify the values which would be left as blank
        self.name = Name;
        self.sname = Surname;
        self.age = Age;
        self.balance = Balance;
# another code here
```

Then, if you pass only part of data to class constructor, you'll still get a working class instance without any errors:

```
>>> a = Customer('Name', 'Surname')
>>> a.Name
'Name'
>>> a.Surname
'Surname'
>>> a.Age
>>>         # we got None here
```

Of course, you can use keyboard input too to enter the values, which is not provided by your csv data file by using the `input()` function.